# Java - change variable type in entity class from database

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, inheritance

I have the following columns in my **database**
[image]
As you see each **Game** has a **Player** that won.
Now I've created **entity classes** from database and I have the following fields in a class Game
[image]
Now I want to add a the second type of Player - **Computer**, which has some **additional** fields, that is why I've created **abstract** class Gamer, that Computer and Player **inherits** from it. And my **question** is: How can i change in entity class that the winner can be **either** Player or a Computer. Do I need to somehow add a table to the database that represents the computer? Or can I somehow change the field to by type of the Gamer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Java EE 7 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/) from Oracle on the topic of [Entity Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro002.htm) and you should find the solution to your problem.

Independently, the question in that case is, if you really need this abstraction, or if it would not suit you better to have a general player entity with an enum to distinguish the type of player (human, computer) for your game and have the personal data of a player separate from that.